# Can't seem to get a linq bound datagrid to be savable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagrid

This seems like it should be simple, but I have fought with it for 2 days now.

I have a datagrid, filling it with a linq query, letting the user edit it, then saving it via subchanges.

This works:

```
Dim reportdata2 = From t In db.Inventory_Items Select t
```

But it obviously returns all the columns...so..tried this:

```
Dim reportdata2 = From t In db.Inventory_Items Select t.Description, t.Customer
```

Looks fine but won't let me edit - seems read only, OK...avoid anonymous type by creating a simple class:

```
Dim reportdata2 = From t In db.Inventory_Items Select New testInventory With {.Item_Desc = t.Description}
```

Now I can edit it, but when I go to submitchanges, it does not throw an error but it does NOT save to the database.

What is the world am I missing?

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not editing any of the objects from your data context.  You're getting those objects, getting some of the data from them and putting it into new objects, then modifying those new objects.  Modifying those new objects doesn't affect the original objects so there's no changes in those original objects to save back to the database.

If you're not actually going to modify the original objects in the first place, you have to map the changes from your new objects back to those original objects and then save those changes.  That would mean something like, before saving, getting a list from your data context, looping through it and updating each one from the corresponding `testInventory` object.  Either that or adding items to the data context that are flagged as being modified rather than new.

Comment: So, you mean something like add a column called "changed" - then whenever they hit saved looping through the entire datagrid looking for rows flagged - and somehow writing out that row to the database?  Seems to render having a datacontext useless?  It just seems like it would be easier to just go back to ADO.  This is such a common need it just seems like it should be something fairly straight forward to do -- are you sure I am not missing something?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. Yes, you are missing something. What I said was that you need to map the changes from the objects you used at the UI layer to the objects in your data context and then save the changes from your data context back to the database.